# How to use a dynamic optionText?

Tags: react-admin

We have the following that displays a select style UX:

```
    <ReferenceInput source="visibility.visibilityId" reference="projectVisibilities" allowEmpty>
      <SelectInput optionText="visibility" />
    </ReferenceInput>
```

We want to add in parentheses the `description` within `visibility`.

Something like this :

```
    <ReferenceInput source="visibility.visibilityId" reference="projectVisibilities" allowEmpty>
      <SelectInput optionText={["visibility", "(", "description", ")" } />
    </ReferenceInput>
```

An unfound string would be rendered as a regular string and `visibility` and `description` as the optionText of the select input, after joining the array.

Is this something already possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`optionText` accepts a function, so you can shape the option text at will:

```
const optionRenderer = choice => `${choice.visibility} (${choice.description})`;

<SelectInput optionText={optionRenderer} />
```

optionText even accepts a React Element, that will be cloned and receive the related choice as the record prop. You can use Field components there:

```
const DescriptionField = ({ record }) => <span>{record.visibility} ({record.description})</span>;

<SelectInput optionText={<DescriptionField />}/>
```

Note that this is clearly documented in the React-admin documentation:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#selectinput

Comment: I knew it was somewhere I just couldn't find it. I wil reread everything in depth asap. Thanks